# Nodejs Mongodb driver: how to combine index hint and projections

Tags: node.js, mongodb, node-mongodb-native

Struggling to combine index hints and query projections with the Nodejs driver.

This works if we only include a hint:

```
db.collection('battle').find({}, {'hint': 'myindex'}).toArray();
```

This works if we only include a projection:

```
db.collection('battle').find({}, {'result.replay': 0}).toArray();
```

but, this ignores the projection:

```
db.collection('battle').find({}, {'hint': 'myindex', 'result.replay': 0}).toArray();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems I had the order incorrect:

```
var cursor = collection.find(query, [fields], options);
```

which means:

```
db.collection('battle').find({}, {'result.replay': 0}, {'hint': 'myindex'}).toArray();
```